# Different excecution plan for same query on 11g and 10g with same database structure and indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a live server where 11g is installed there i tried to run query on a view and takes several minutes(3-5 min). Then I exported the whole schema and imported on 10g and there it takes about 145msec.
Here is the query:

```
Select Rec.*
From VW_HS_ADMNPATIENTCURRENTINFO Rec
where (0=0) AND ISDischarged = 'N' and ISDISINDEPOSIT = 'N'
  and INPTDATE >='2076/01/01' and INPTDATE <= '2076/01/05'
```

[10g plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EgBG.png)

[11g plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzYkt.png)

Comment: having different exec plans between versions happens. Sometimes for the better, sometimes not. So, in your case, there seems to be a big difference in the last part of the plan (probably one of your views). Check that you have the proper stats on all objects, and then try again. Aside question: you're now migrating from 10g to 11g? You surely know that 11g is practically out of support.

Comment: Statistics differences?

Comment: What exactly is the question ?